# pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Failed to connect to browser port

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pyppeteer, python-requests-html

I have problems when using `requests-html` package on Python 3.6.5, Ubuntu 16.04(x64). To be more specific, the last line of

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://python-requests.org/')
r.html.render()
```

produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>
> File
>   "/home/candy/.conda/envs/candy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py",
>   line 572, in render 
>       self.session.browser  # Automatycally create a event loop and browser
>
> File
>   "/home/candy/.conda/envs/candy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py",
>   line 680, in browser
>       self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(pyppeteer.launch(headless=True,
>   args=['--no-sandbox']))
>
> File
>   "/home/candy/.conda/envs/candy_env/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py",
>   line 468, in run_until_complete
>       return future.result()
>
> File
>   "/home/candy/.conda/envs/candy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py",
>   line 243, in launch
>       return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
>
> File
>   "/home/candy/.conda/envs/candy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py",
>   line 160, in launch
>       self.browserWSEndpoint = self._get_ws_endpoint()
>
> File
>   "/home/candy/.conda/envs/candy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py",
>   line 178, in _get_ws_endpoint
>       raise BrowserError(f'Failed to connect to browser port: {url}')
>
> pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Failed to connect to browser port:
>   http://127.0.0.1:43623/json/version

However, the same code works well without errors on another Windows 10 platform, with the same Python requirements configured.

I have checked whether a Chrome has been downloaded successfully on my computer and the result is yes! So I think that's not where the problem is.

> (candy_env)
>   candy@botwriter01:~/.pyppeteer/local-chromium/543305/chrome-linux$ ls
>   chrome
>                     chrome_sandbox  libclearkeycdm.so  locales      nacl_helper_bootstrap  natives_blob.bin     resources.pak
>   xdg-mime chrome_100_percent.pak  chrome-wrapper  libEGL.so
>   MEIPreload   nacl_helper_nonsfi     product_logo_48.png  swiftshader
>   xdg-settings chrome_200_percent.pak  icudtl.dat      libGLESv2.so
>   nacl_helper  nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe   resources
>   v8_context_snapshot.bin

I have already searched the guidebook of `requests-html` for answers but got nothing found. I want the command `r.html.render()` to work correctly, what can I do now?

Comment: Thanks for you kind formatting, it's quit pretty now~ I'll pay attention to that the next time~